# webforms routing multiple word

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, url-routing

this is my routing pattern.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("villadetail", "{sublocationurl}-bali-{villaurl}-details", "~/VillaDetail.aspx");
```

sample values:

```
sublocationurl = "pemuteran"
villaurl = "jeda-villa-bali-3br"
```

url:

```
www.website.com/pemuteran-bali-jeda-villa-bali-3br-details
```

problem arises when same multiple words appear in the url and in this case the word is "bali".

```
Page.RouteData.Values["sublocationurl"]
```

results in **pemuteran-bali-jeda-villa** instead of **"pemuteran"**

and

`Page.RouteData.Values["villaurl"]` results in **3br** instead of **"jeda-villa-bali-3br"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a trivial problem in fact. I overlooked the special property of the hyphen as separator.

You can go for a custom route which will correct your parameters ( idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14075552/1236044 ) :

```
public class CustomRoute : Route
{
    private String _separator;

    public CustomRoute(string url,
        RouteValueDictionary defaults,
        RouteValueDictionary constraints,
        RouteValueDictionary dataTokens,String separator,IRouteHandler hdl)
        : base(url, defaults, constraints, dataTokens, hdl)
    {

        _separator = separator;
    }

    protected override bool ProcessConstraint(HttpContextBase httpContext,
        object constraint, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values,
        RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if(((string)values["sublocationurl"]).Contains(_separator))
        {
            var wholeParams = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", values["sublocationurl"],_separator, values["villaurl"]).Split(new[]{_separator},StringSplitOptions.None);
            values["sublocationurl"] = wholeParams[0].Trim('-');
            values["villaurl"] = String.Join(_separator, wholeParams.Skip(1)).Trim('-');
        }
        return base.ProcessConstraint(httpContext, constraint,
            parameterName, values, routeDirection);
    }
}
```

The route can then be registered like this :

```
var separator = "bali";

routes.Add("villadetail",
            new CustomRoute("{sublocationurl}-"+separator+"-{villaurl}-details",
            new RouteValueDictionary(),
            new RouteValueDictionary{{ "sublocationurl", @".+"}},
            new RouteValueDictionary()
            , separator, new System.Web.Routing.PageRouteHandler("~/VillaDetail.aspx",false)));
```

Hope this will help

----------Previous non working answer

You may try to add a regex constraint to your sublocation url parameter to state that it must not contain "bali".

Something like this :

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "villadetail", 
    "{sublocationurl}-bali-{villaurl}-details", 
     "~/VillaDetail.aspx", 
     true, // checkPhysicalUrlAccess, value at  your will
     defaults:new RouteValueDictionary {},
     constraints: new RouteValueDictionary { { "sublocationurl", @"((?!bali).)*"}})
```

Comment: restricting values for {villaurl} is not an option for me. I just need some way for the routing to get the correct value. :(

Comment: @vhinnterrible my answer does not restrict values on {villaurl}. It restrict values on {sublocationurl}. Have you  tried it ? With route pattern, if you want to get the correct values, you can not allow sublocationurl to contain 'bali'

Comment: ooops.. sorry I overlooked. i was focusing on villaurl. anyways, tried it now and results in "Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found." :(